# Is it possible to join or bind data together in google sheets?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I'm looking for a way to accomplish data binding (join data) in Google sheets.

I have two sheets (A = Form Responses and B = Report w/Notes). I need data from sheetA to be moved into sheetB. SheetB needs to bind (join) imported data from sheetA with manually entered data in sheetB.

**SheetA = From Responses**

```
(A)Date     (B)Fname     (C)Lname     (D)ID#
1-2-17      Tod          Smith        123456
1-3-17      Jen          Jones        234567
1-5-17      Bob          Craft        345678
```

**SheetB = Report w/Notes**
- in reverse chronological order

```
(A)Date     (B)Fname     (C)Lname     (D)ID#        (E)Notes
1-5-17      Bob          Craft        345678        Good kid
1-2-17      Tod          Smith        123456        Always late
1-3-17      Jen          Jones        234567        Very helpful
```

I need the "notes" column data to bind to the data in columns A-D when a new record is submitted into sheetA and imported into sheetB, the data in column (E)Notes moves down and remains properly aligned with the student data.

**SheetB = Report w/Notes**
CURRENT outcome when new record is submitted

```
    (A)Date     (B)Fname     (C)Lname     (D)ID#        (E)Notes
    1-7-17      New          Kid          456789        Good kid    
    1-5-17      Bob          Craft        345678        Always late
    1-2-17      Tod          Smith        123456        Very helpful
    1-3-17      Jen          Jones        234567
```

You'll see the new student info is imported into sheetB, but the notes in (E)Notes are not properly aligned with their student.

**SheetB = Report w/Notes**
DESIRED outcome when new record is submitted

```
    (A)Date     (B)Fname     (C)Lname     (D)ID#        (E)Notes
    1-7-17      New          Kid          456789            
    1-5-17      Bob          Craft        345678        Good kid
    1-2-17      Tod          Smith        123456        Always late
    1-3-17      Jen          Jones        234567        Very helpful
```

You'll see the new student info is imported into sheetB, and it has been automatically 'moved' down a row so it stays properly aligned with the appropriate student.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted to Web Applications and cross-posting is discouraged on [se].

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want but it's a script that combines all of the other sheets in a spreadsheet into one sheet named combinesheets.

```
function combinesheets()
{
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var allsheets = ss.getSheets(); 
 var combineSht = ss.getSheetByName("combinesheets"); 
 for (var i=0; i<allsheets.length; i++) 
 {
   if (shtName != 'combinesheets')
   {
     var shtName = allsheets[i].getName();
     var sht = ss.getSheetByName(shtName);
     var shtrng = sht.getDataRange();
     var shtrngA = shtrng.getValues(); 
     for(var j=0;j<shtrngA.length;j++)
     {
       combineSht.appendRow(shtrngA[j]);
     }
   }
 }
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

So perhaps this will give you a start and we might be able to modify it into something that fits your needs.

Comment: thanks for your input. I do see value in this solution, but my project will only have 2 sheets.

Comment: Okay then change 'combinesheets' to the name of the sheet you want join the other with.